# How to reverse colorbar values in matpotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

I am using the `cbar.ax.tick_params` matplotlib command to make a colorbar for an XY scatterplot. How do I reverse the values (not the color-ramp) so that the lowest value is at the top of the bar. This is to represent geological data where the youngest rocks are on top of the older rocks. Here the age is represented by color.

Here is my code:

```
plt.scatter(summary["d18O"], summary["eHf"], s=150, c = color, cmap = color_map, edgecolors='black', marker='o')
plt.errorbar(summary["d18O"], summary["eHf"], summary["xerr"], summary["yerr"], ls='none', color='lightgrey', zorder=-1)

cbar=plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
cbar.minorticks_on()
cbar.set_label('Age (Ma)', style='italic', fontsize=16)

plt.axvline(x=5.3, color='black', zorder=-1)
plt.axhline(y=0, color='black', zorder=-1)

plt.tick_params(labelsize=14)
ax.set_xticks([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])
ax.set_yticks([-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16])
plt.ylabel(u'${\epsilon}$Hf$_{T}$', style='italic', fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel(u'$\delta^{18}$O$_{V-SMOW}$ ‰',style='italic', fontsize=18)

plt.text(11.5, 0.3, 'CHUR', fontsize=18)
plt.text(4.9, 5, 'mantle zircon = 5.3‰', fontsize=16, rotation=90)



plt.show()
```

Comment: `cbar.ax.invert_yaxis()`Wouldn't this be effective?

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @r-beginners mentioned,

```
cbar.ax.invert_yaxis()
```

would solve the problem if `cbar` is your colorer object.